# how to select a node from xml file?

Tags: xml, asp-classic

Below is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>

<book category="cooking">
<book>
    <bookID>1111</bookID>
</book>
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="children">
<book>
    <bookID>54655</bookID>
</book>
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
<book>
    <bookID>5556</bookID>
</book>
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<author>James McGovern</author>
<author>Per Bothner</author>
<author>Kurt Cagle</author>
<author>James Linn</author>
<author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web" cover="paperback">
<book>
    <bookID>1111</bookID>
</book>
<title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
<author>Erik T. Ray</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

I need to display "Title" of the books.

Below asp code i used to display data

```
<%
'' #Load XML

Set xml= Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
    xml.async = False
    xml.load (Server.MapPath("test.xml"))

    if xml.parseError.errorcode<>0 then
    response.write   "error handling code" &xml.parseError.errorcode
    else

        Set objLst= xml.getElementsByTagName("bookstore").item(0).getElementsByTagName("book")
        TotalBooks = (objLst.Length)-1
        For i=0 to eval(TotalBooks)
            response.write xml.getElementsByTagName("bookstore").item(0).getElementsByTagName("book").item(i).getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text&"<br/>"
        Next

    end if

%>
```

But "objLst.length"  showing the sub node of `<book>`

in this cause i getting error

the code display only the fist node book title only . it not goes to the second node. hw i fix it?

```
i need out put like below

Everyday Italian

Harry Potter

XQuery Kick Start

Learning XML
```

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use System.Xml.Linq as @sonjz suggested then you can use [SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754523%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and an XPath expression

```
set nodes = xml.documentElement.selectNodes("//book/title")

for each node in nodes
    response.write node.text & "<br/>"
next
```

Answer (score -1):

Use System.Xml.Linq, that will be the easiest.

Load it into an XElement and use Linq to query it.

```
XDocument test = XDocument.Load(xmlFilename); // load from string if you want
XElement cooking = test.Element("bookstore")
                       .Descendants("book")
                       .Where(e => e.Attribute("category" => "cooking")
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: -1 This is an ASP-Classic question, XDocument/Linq is unavailable.

Comment: note there is a strange thing I remember with XPath,
selectNodes (gets list) and selectSingleNode (first occurance)

xml.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//book[category='cooking']")